# Jenkins Database and Authentication

Tags: jenkins

Does Jenkins store build status information into a database on its own? Does it have a plugin to talk to an Oracle database? If yes, can the slaves running on remote sites do this on their own, without master having to do the database interaction?

I will be running Jenkins on remote sites.Won't network hiccups cause master to think that the build has failed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Does Jenkins store build status information into a database on its own?

Everything is stored locally in XML files on the master.

> Does it have a plugin to talk to an Oracle database?

No, for the reason above.

> Won't network hiccups cause master to think that the build has failed?

Yes.

Answer (score 8):

You can configure [Audit to Database](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin) plugin to store build data into DB using oracle, mysql, postgres, etc.

Regards!

Comment: I was looking for this bug this plugin had the last release more than 3 years ago which make me think that is probably not safe to run on current versions of Jenkins.

Comment: yes, it's quite long ago last update. I've tried to get in touch with maintainers but I had no luck to check/update some errors.

Actually if you need analysis tool I'll look for another plugin to connect to systems like kibana to perform analysis:
* Official: https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cjoc-user-guide/analytics.html
*  Handmade: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T78705

Regards!

Comment: is there a new database plugin for the latest version of jenkins available ?